# Flutter serialize from json depending on type

Tags: json, flutter, dart, serialization

I want to convert a nested model to the correct model depending on the type. I know that @JsonKey can be used to specifically handle certain properties. However, how can I access other properties on fromJson? The fromJson method has to be static, but then I cannot access the other properties. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

```
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true, nullable: true)
class Model {
  int type;
  @JsonKey(
    name: 'action',
    fromJson: _convertActionToModel,
  )
  dynamic action;

  Model({this.type, this.action});

  factory Model.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ModelFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ModelToJson(this);

  static dynamic _convertActionToModel(dynamic json) {
    switch (type) {  // How can i get this type?
      case 0:
        return OtherModel.fromJson(json as Map<String, dynamic>);
        break;
      ....
    }
  }
```

How can I get the type for the switch case?

Answer (score 0):

Your json is just a map<String, Object>, you could do:

```
var type = json['typeKey'] as String (or int, bool);
```

Comment: But if i use the @JsonKey for the fromJson i only get the property "action" in the _convertActionToModel method and not the whole json object or am I wrong?

Comment: You are right, if your json is { "action": "doSomething"} in or converAction u will get only the string "doSomething" - _convertActionToModel(String json)

Comment: So there is no way to get another property of the model if i use the serialization?